# Stressing out SSHD server with multiple requests from same server

Tags: ssh, stress-testing

I am doing a customer demo where I need to stress out a sshd server with repeated sequential requests. So I wrote a small shell script with a loop in it. The first connection is successful, however the sshd refuses connection immediately after the first connection. So all my subsequent requests fail.

Right now the SSHD is running in a docker container and I am running the script from the host. So no external factor such as network proxy is in picture here.

So far I have checked the following things

The SSHD config file contains the following line (I bumped up the value)
MaxStartups 100:300:600

Checked everything here - http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification

Have been googling around for what could be the problem  (too many links to post here). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So the SSHD daemon was being spawned in the debug mode. Therefore it could not fork. It would get killed after one connection. Tried putting it in the regular mode and now the test is flying :)